# How to pass basic auth along with post request in Frisby?

Tags: javascript, rest, frisby.js

Trying to test rest api. In my project there is no api for login. whenever you hit the api it is being redirect to login , takes user/pass and give you result.

I tried GET as follows which is working fine for me.

```
    var frisby = require('frisby')
    var url = 'https://localhost:8443';
    var api= '/api/v2/events/details'
    var endpoint = '?id=ccce2aef971f'
    var user= 'demo@demo.com'
    var pass= 'temp'

    frisby.create('GET event details based on eventid from an endpoint')
   .get(url+api+endpoint,{strictSSL: false})
   .auth(user,pass,false)
   .expectStatus(200)
   .expectHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8')
   .toss();
```

now I want to use POST method with same format but no luck in response.

```
var frisby = require('frisby')
var user= 'demo@demo.com'
var pass= 'temp'
var jsonbody = {"group": "a10bbd20",
        "category":"Attack",
        "notes":"abcdddd",
        "criteria":[  {"attribute":"PATH" ,"operator": "EQUALS", "value":"/Account/demo.aspx" }]
        }

frisby.create('TEST POST')
.post('https://localhost:8443/api/v2/rule-settings/pointwise',jsonbody,{ json: true },{ headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }},{strictSSL: false})
.auth(user,pass,false)

.expectStatus(201)
.toss();
```

======================

I tried to do POST request by storing cookie from previous response but still same error for time out

```
var frisby = require('frisby')
var url = 'https://localhost:8443';
var api= '/api/v2/events/details'
var endpoint = '?id=ccce2aef971f'
var user= 'demo@demo.com'
var pass= 'temp'


var loginState = {
};


    frisby.create('GET event details based on eventid from an endpoint')
    .get(url+api+endpoint,{strictSSL: false})
    .auth(user,pass,false)
        .after(function (body,res) {
            var cookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];
            console.log(cookie);
            loginState.user1 = {}; // build an object for user 1
            loginState.user1.cookie = cookie;                
            var jsonbody = {"group": "a10bbd20",
                            "category":"Attack",
                            "notes":"abcdddd",
                            "criteria":[  {"attribute":"PATH" ,"operator": "EQUALS", "value":"/Account/demo.aspx" }]
                            }

        frisby.create('TEST POST')
        .post('https://localhost:8443/api/v2/rule-settings/pointwise',jsonbody,{ json: true },{strictSSL: false})
        .addHeader('cookie', loginState.user1.cookie) 
        .addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .inspectRequest()
        .expectStatus(201)
        .toss();
        })

        .toss();
```

output I am getting is

```
Message:
Expected 500 to equal 200.
Stacktrace:
Error: Expected 500 to equal 200.
at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestSuite\node_modules
\frisby\lib\frisby.js:493:42)
at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestSuite\node_modules
\frisby\lib\frisby.js:1074:43)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after couple of search and frisby issue page.

need to add environment variable to bypass certificate. 
add **process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";** before post method and everything is good to go.

one more thing, it will work with regular post request as well. no need to chain get,post together for cookies.